# WeakValueDictionary for holding any type

Tags: python

Is there any way to work around the limitations of WeakValueDictionary to allow it to hold weak references to built-in types like dict or list?  Can something be done at the C level in an extension module?  I really need a weakref container that can hold (nearly) any type of object.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/weakref.html) you can create weak references to subclasses of `dict` and `list`... it's not a perfect solution, but if you're able to create a custom subclass of `dict` and use that instead of a native `dict`, it should be good enough. (I've never actually done this myself)

Comment: The problem is that the object to be stored in this container will be coming from other people's code, and the container is an "implementation detail" of a larger set of classes, so I would rather avoid a "must be weak-referencable" kind of requirement.

Comment: ah... well, I don't know of any way to create a fully general WeakValueDictionary that can hold anything at all. There are various tricks you can use in special cases, though - if you edit the question to specify what kinds of objects you need to have weak references to, it might help.